# Api call from frontend to backend running on different ports

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, frontend, backend

i have frontend project running on different port then the backend project.

My nextjs project is running on port 3990 and nodejs running on port 3991. From my frontend i want make the api call to the backend what i do is this:

example :

```
export const signup = async (user) => {
  return fetch(`http://localhost:3991/api/signup`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return { status: 'fail', message: 'API CALL ERROR', error: err.message };
    });
};
```

I receive this :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

On development is was working but now on production it isn't.

Frontend have it's own domain and backend is just running on localhost

Comment: Surely your production backend isn't on `localhost` from the client's viewpoint? :)

Comment: You're trying to make a request to localhost from a web hosted frontend?

Comment: @Canta Both are hosted on a server but frontend has a domain https://frontendexample.com ... backend nothing just running on the server

Comment: You're targetting what like, <backend IP>:<Port?>. Did you also check firewall rules?

Comment: just like : http://localhost:3991/api/signup

Comment: So... client requests are not made in the server, but in the client, i.e.: in the browser of user. In that context, "localhost" points to client own localhost, not server. Backend needs, at least, a public ip

Comment: @Canta Yes , it was my bad it didn't thought about it. Tried using proxy but didn't worked so created  api.frontendexample.com